# User in SharePoint Group get access is required message

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint Site where I created a List and I want to give read and add access to this list only to a limited group of people.

1. First I created in the SP site the List "ListX"
2. In the ListX settings I went to list permissions and I stopped inheriting permissions from the site and I created unique permissions
3. On the site advanced permission settings I created a new permission level "Add and View Only" where I selected the following options:

   - On the list permissions section
     (a) Add Items  -  Add items to lists and add documents to document libraries
     (b) View Items  -  View items in lists and documents in document libraries
   - The moment I selected those two options the following options have been automatically selected for me on the site permissions section:
     (a) View Pages  -  View pages in a Web site
     (b) Open  -  Allows users to open a Web site, list, or folder in order to access items inside that container
4. Then on the site permission I created a SharePoint group "ListX Users" and I gave the permission level "Add and View Only"
5. Then I added several users in the SP group "ListX Users"
6. Then I granted permissions on the ListX permissions to the "ListX Users" SP group

However the user gets the message "Sorry you don't have access" when they try to go to the top level of the site so that they can click on the ListX link and they are prompted to request access.

Any idea why that happens and how to give such Add and View access to the ListX only? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Best (and easiest) imo is to work down. Give them permissions on site level and break inheritance on each library that shouldn't be visible for everyone.

That way the navigation is the easiest and for maintenance has the easiest overview.

[image: SharePoint permission structure]

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved my issue by adding two more options in the List permissions permission levels of "Add and View Only". See below.
    Open Items  -  View the source of documents with server-side file handlers
    View Application Pages  -  View forms, views, and application pages. Enumerate lists

However in this case the user need to have a direct link to the list and cannot navigate via the site.